# (PostgreSQL) actual record number in recordset

Tags: sql, postgresql

Ffor testing purposes I need to write a SQL query which contains the 
actual record number as a column in the result set. If my SELECT gets
back to me with 10 records as the result, I need to have one column
which contains the values 1-10.

Is there a way to achieve this without a stored procedure cursoring through
my data?

I need this on PostgreSQL.

Comment: For postgresql see:
[Simulating Row Number in PostgreSQL Pre 8.4](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/index.php?/archives/79-Simulating-Row-Number-in-PostgreSQL-Pre-8.4.html)

Comment: @cœur how's that?

Comment: @JohnSaunders even better, thanks :)

Answer (score 8):

You could partition your data and get a row_number()

For example:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, SalesYTD, PostalCode, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SalesYTD DESC) AS 'Row Number'
FROM Sales.vSalesPerson
WHERE TerritoryName IS NOT NULL AND SalesYTD <> 0;
```

See the following:
[ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Comment: The good thing about this solution is it will work for any RDBMS that is written to the ISO SQL:2003 standard.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) (SQL Server 2005 and above)

Answer (score 2):

If you're on 8.4, you can use [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) (row_number() to be exact).

If you're on pre 8.4, you can use the technique I [described](http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2007/08/17/rownum-anyone-cumulative-sum-in-one-query/) some time ago on my [blog](http://www.depesz.com/).