# Generate a random number in the range 1 - 10

Tags: sql, postgresql, random

Since my approach for a test query which I worked on in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400056/postgress-actual-record-number-in-recordset) did not work out, I'm trying something else now. Is there a way to tell pg's `random()` function to get me only numbers between 1 and 10?

Answer (score 195, accepted):

If by numbers between 1 and 10 you mean any float that is >= 1 and < 10, then it's easy:

```
select random() * 9 + 1
```

This can be easily tested with:

```
# select min(i), max(i) from (
    select random() * 9 + 1 as i from generate_series(1,1000000)
) q;
       min       |       max
-----------------+------------------
 1.0000083274208 | 9.99999571684748
(1 row)
```

If you want integers, that are >= 1 and < 10, then it's simple:

```
select trunc(random() * 9 + 1)
```

And again, simple test:

```
# select min(i), max(i) from (
    select trunc(random() * 9 + 1) as i from generate_series(1,1000000)
) q;
 min | max
-----+-----
   1 |   9
(1 row)
```

Comment: select date(e.created_at) + (trunc(random()  * 20)) from events e;
result in:
ERROR:  operator does not exist: date + double precision
Does trunc really return integers?

Comment: `trunc()` returns the same data type as the input (as stated in the manual). You need to cast the result to an integer: `trunc(random() * 20)::int`

Comment: I wonder if at least in theory it is possible that `random()` would return a value <1 that when multiplied by 9 would be >=9 due to the [inexact nature of the double precision type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT)? In practice even if it is possible it would be vanishingly unlikely of course because of the 15 digits or so precision.

Comment: I'm toying with `width_bucket(random(), 0, 1, 10)` as an alternative

Comment: It looks like [my fears were groundless](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/3186/2515) though I confess I don't understand the maths at all :-)

Comment: this is not correct for SQL, In SQL 2014 i got error 'random' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Answer (score 22):

To summarize and a bit simplify, you can use:

```
-- 0 - 9
select floor(random() * 10);
-- 0 - 10
SELECT floor(random() * (10 + 1));
-- 1 - 10
SELECT ceil(random() * 10);
```

And you can test this like mentioned by @user80168

```
-- 0 - 9
SELECT min(i), max(i) FROM (SELECT floor(random() * 10) AS i FROM generate_series(0, 100000)) q;
-- 0 - 10
SELECT min(i), max(i) FROM (SELECT floor(random() * (10 + 1)) AS i FROM generate_series(0, 100000)) q;
-- 1 - 10
SELECT min(i), max(i) FROM (SELECT ceil(random() * 10) AS i FROM generate_series(0, 100000)) q;
```

Comment: The [docs say](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-math.html) "random value in the range 0.0 <= x < 1.0", so there is at least a theoretical chance of `ceil(random() * 10)` resulting in 0 — I would stick to `floor`.

Comment: I agree with @JackDouglas, so for the range 1 - 10 it should be `SELECT floor(random() * 10 + 1);`

Answer (score 13):

If you are using SQL Server then correct way to get integer is

```
SELECT Cast(RAND()*(b-a)+a as int);
```

Where

- 'b' is the upper limit
- 'a' is lower limit

Comment: Be careful here, if you put your lower limit as 1 and upper as 10, you will only get numbers 1->9. Other answers seem to assume that Between 1 and 10 means 1->9... I would suggest if 'between' excludes the upper bound it should also exclude the lower (ie 2->9). SELECT Cast(RAND()*((b+1)-a)+a as int);

Comment: The question is clearly tagged as a PostgreSQL question.

Answer (score 4):

(trunc(random() * 10) % 10) + 1

Comment: ERROR:  operator does not exist: double precision % integer

Comment: And why would you use modulus anyway? This logic doesn't make sense. If you get any "wrapping" you won't have equal distribution, and if you don't get any, then you don't need it.

Answer (score 4):

Using Postgres, here is how to generate random number between any 2 numbers, say, `min` and `max`:

Including `min` and Excluding `max`,

```
SELECT floor(random() * (max - min)) + min;
```

Including both `min` and `max`,

```
SELECT floor(random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
```

So to get numbers between 1 and 10 (including 10),

min = 1, max = 10

```
SELECT floor(random() * (10 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
```

In general, you can use this formula to get random integer numbers between any min and max numbers.

Answer (score 2):

The correct version of hythlodayr's answer.

```
-- ERROR:  operator does not exist: double precision % integer
-- LINE 1: select (trunc(random() * 10) % 10) + 1
```

The output from `trunc` has to be converted to `INTEGER`. But it can be done without `trunc`. So it turns out to be simple.

```
select (random() * 9)::INTEGER + 1
```

Generates an INTEGER output in range [1, 10] i.e. both 1 & 10 inclusive.

For any number (floats), see user80168's answer. i.e just don't convert it to `INTEGER`.

Answer (score 2):

Example

```
SELECT RAND()*(min-max)+max
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't know you want to this.

try this

```
INSERT INTO my_table (my_column)
SELECT
    (random() * 10) + 1
;
```

Answer (score 0):

This stored procedure inserts a rand number into a table. Look out, it inserts an endless numbers. Stop executing it when u get enough numbers.

create a table for the cursor:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SearchIndex](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Cursor] [nvarchar](255) NULL)
```

GO

Create a table to contain your numbers:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ID](
[IDN] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ID] [int] NULL)
```

INSERTING THE SCRIPT :

```
INSERT INTO [SearchIndex]([Cursor])  SELECT N'INSERT INTO ID  SELECT   FLOOR(rand() * 9 + 1)  SELECT COUNT (ID) FROM ID
```

CREATING AND EXECUTING THE PROCEDURE:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[RandNumbers] AS
BEGIN
Declare  CURSE  CURSOR  FOR (SELECT  [Cursor] FROM [dbo].[SearchIndex]  WHERE [Cursor] IS NOT NULL)
DECLARE @RandNoSscript NVARCHAR (250)
OPEN CURSE
FETCH NEXT FROM CURSE
INTO @RandNoSscript 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN
Print @RandNoSscript
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @RandNoSscript;  
 END
 END
GO
```

Fill your table:

```
EXEC RandNumbers
```

Comment: The question is about Postgres, not SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
Select (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ItemDesc ASC)+15000) as ID, ItemCode, ItemDesc
```