# PostgreSQL: change date by the random number of days

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, random

How can I change the date by the random number of days in PostgreSQL?

Unfortunately 
[Generate a random number in the range 1 - 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400505/postgresql-random-number-range-1-10)
solution with trunc doesn't work:

```
select date(now()) + (trunc(random()  * 20))
```

results in:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: date + double precision
LÍNEA 1: select date(now()) + (trunc(random()  * 20))
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
select date(now() + trunc(random()  * 20) * '1 day'::interval);
```

Any existing date column can also be used in place of `now()`

See: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html

Answer (score 4):

How random? For example - if you want random data from last year:

```
select cast( now() - '1 year'::interval * random()  as date );
```