# How to insert random polygons within certain area or square km in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgis

How to insert/create any random points within certain area or square km (say for mumbai)

Considering area is mumbai and I want to insert all possible random points that lies within this area

My idea was to write custom function in Postgres like stored procedure

Specific : I need to have a fixed area that is mumbai .. and within this area i want to generate some small polygons , my concern is that how can i get the cordinates of mumbai , or how i can insert using boundary cordinates of mumbai?

Comment: *insert **all** possible random points* - are you sure? There are infinite number of (random) points in an area.

Comment: not  sure about wanted to test it for load balance .. suppose given a polygon , how many small polygons lies inside that polygon within that whole area( for ex mumbai )

Comment: if you want to break down a polygon into smaller chunks, that's a different question; please update this one or post a new.

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear. Random points will not create a useful, valid polygon. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Create a table named 'Location' with two decimal columns, x and y.

Insert records using [`random()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-math.html) to generate co-ordinates, with your specified max for x and y.

You can do this in a function, but why not straight in a SQL statement - you can execute it from the command line or pgAdmin.

Stackoverflow answer on how to use random: [Generate a random number in the range 1 - 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400505/generate-a-random-number-in-the-range-1-10)

**EDIT - Additional information for polygon requirement after original question edit**

Add an extra column to 'Location' of type Integer, name it shape_id

For every shape_id there will be three or more rows, for the three+ points of a polygon.

When inserting locations into the table you will need to check the previous entries for that shape_id, and be sure it satisfies the rules of a polygon.

Comment: If you use random() to create a polygon you will end up with spaghetti. There are more sophisticated algorithms to create non self-intersecting polygons, but the OP question is somewhat vague about what is required, it has to be said.

Comment: @JohnBarça the question was modified to add the polygon requirement, that was not there previously. I could modify the answer or delete it, as you're right it would generate 'spaghetti'.