# Generating a random 10-digit ID number in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, random

I apologize if this has been answered elsewhere. I found similar posts but nothing that exactly matches what I was looking for. I am wondering if it is possible to randomly assign a number as data is entered into a table. For example, for this table

```
CREATE TABLE test (
id_number INTEGER NOT NULL,
second_number INTEGER NOT NULL)
```

I would like to be able to do the following:

```
INSERT INTO test (second_number)
VALUES (1234567)
```

where id_number is then populated with a random 10-digit number. I guess I want this similar to SERIAL in the way it populates but it needs to be 10 digits and random. Thanks very much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate a random number in the range 1 - 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400505/generate-a-random-number-in-the-range-1-10)

Answer (score 4):

You can try this expression:

```
CAST(1000000000 + floor(random() * 9000000000) AS bigint)
```

This will give you a random number between 1000000000 and 9999999999.